# Find the missing number from the pyramid

Tags: calculation-puzzle, missing-digits

```
         ?
       1   3
     3   3   9
   9   3   1   9
```

Find the missing number in the pyramid?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Answer:

> 3

Solution:

> Divide the larger of the two numbers in the cells below by the smaller of the 2 numbers.

---

> ```
>  Original Pyramid  |     Calculations 
>                    |
>          ?         |         3/1
>        1   3       |      3/3   9/3
>      3   3   9     |   9/3   3/1   9/1
>    9   3   1   9   |  9    3     1     9
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is 1/3

because(3/9)/(1/3)=1

and 1/(1/3)=3

3/(1/3)=9

With the same calculations we can obtain the rest of the numbers 1, 3, 9 in the pyramid.